# android studio error: reached end of file while parsing

Tags: android-studio

```
package com.example.vicky.videostory;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnPlay;
    VideoView myvideo;
    MediaController mediaController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPlay=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Play);
        myvideo=(videoView) findviewById(R.id.videoPlayer);

        mediaController = new MediaController( this) ;


        btnPlay.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String videoPath = "android.resource//com.example.vicky.videostory/"+R.raw.technology;
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(videoPath);
                myvideo.setVideoURI(uri);
                myvideo.setMediaController(mediaController);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(myvideo);
                myvideo.start();


            }

        }
    );

}
```

error: reached end of file while parsing
 I think its just errors in brackets. Because when I click on an error it points towards brackets and says unexpected error.

[this is the error please check whats wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O87Lv.png)

Comment: If you really want help i sugest you to write your code and not post it as image, it's easier for getting help.

Comment: Your syntax is not completely okay. Please read documentations or follow tutorials. It seems you don't even understand basics

Comment: check now guys I edit the post if are using android studio u will identified the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your syntax correct it first and then `Rebuild Project` also remember that follow the basics properly before doing code.